# the controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement icontroller sitecore

Tags: controller

When we are accessing controller ,we are seeing controller issues

[image: image description: MVC error]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read and edit accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear but here are some things you can check to see why the related controller can not be found.

1. Navigate to the presentation details for the /(home page) and find
   the control(rendering) that was added for placeholder "page-grid".
2. Navigate to the corresponding rendering and find the controller and action 
   method if it is controller rendering.
3. The action method name should be there in your project and the controller 
   name corresponds to that rendering should implement SitecoreController class.